# How to open Commoncrawl.org WARC.GZ S3 Data in Spark

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, apache-spark, common-crawl

I want to access a commoncrawl file from the Amazon public dataset repository from the spark shell. The files are in WARC.GZ format.

```
val filenameList = List("s3://<ID>:<SECRECT>@aws-publicdatasets.s3.amazonaws.com/common-crawl/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2014-41/segments/1410657102753.15/warc/CC-MAIN-20140914011142-00000-ip-10-196-40-205.us-west-1.compute.internal.warc.gz")

// TODO: implement functionality to read the WARC.GZ file here
val loadedFiles = sc.parallelize(filenameList, filenameList.length).mapPartitions(i => i)
loadedFiles.foreach(f => f.take(1))
```

I would now implement a function to read the WARC.GZ format inside the mapPartitions function. Is this a good approach to do that? I ask because i am fairly new to the Spark platform and wanted to implement a small demo application using a small part of the commoncrawl corpus. I saw mapPartitions being used in a thread [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/spark-users/PmJwmFt7H0M/qvs7OBG_VFUJ).

I a first attempt, i tried to open the file directly from my own computer using sc.textFile("s3://....").take(1) which resulted in am access denied error. Are the S3 amazon public repository files accessible only from EC2 instances?

Answer (score 5):

There is an example code from the ["Analyzing Web Domain Vulnerabilities"](http://norvigaward.github.io/naward01/doc/index.html) analysis that shows you how to access WARC files from Spark as Spark supports the Hadoop InputFormat interface. The code itself is hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/norvigaward/naward01/).

We're hoping to provide an example in the Common Crawl GitHub repository soon, as we do for Hadoop using Python and Java.